# Best Practises for Users for automatic login using laravel

Tags: laravel

I was wondering what the best practices for allowing users to automatically login after registration.

In particular does anyone know any php applications auto login after registering.

Honestly, I think it is a horrible idea, but was wondering if anyone knew why the majority of websites don't automatically login newly registered users.

Comment: I think it depends on the case. If the data you get access to after authentication is ultra-sensitive. I would go for forcing authentication again. If its just your data you get after registration I would go for auto-login.

Comment: Some of the website won't allow to login automatically after registration because of some security issue, like making sure that the email is really real and user need to confirm first before accessing the site. 

But sometime auto login can be better for the user because they don't need to login again and repeat what they already done.

In-short it depends on you what you way of authentication you like, however both are having different benefits.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/ianmorris/2017/08/01/when-companies-dont-verify-email-addresses-this-is-what-happens/#4a59243f148e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel's Auth scaffolding logs you in automatically after registration, unless (only in Laravel 5.7) requiring email verification is enabled.

In Laravel 5.7, if you do have email verification enabled, you can still log the user in but only allow certain pages to be accessed only if they have verified their email. So, while the user would still be technically logged in, they haven't verified their email yet thus disabling them from accessing certain content.

An example might be allowing them to log in to be presented with a "Must verify your email" prompt.

In general, I think it's a good idea to require user verification.

Comment: When they made this a feature, it was glorious. It meant that when a user registered, they could start browsing the site and only have to deal with getting their email verified on something like an order form.